# How to use a sprite mask or shader to mask a text?

Tags: unity, shaders, masking

I'd like to know what I need to learn to apply a shader to achieve masking on the text.

Here is my text object in-game, I'm using a sprite mask to mask the game objects on the card, they're all in their own sorting layer, the order number is 11.

Here is my text in the inspector
[image]

However, everything on the card is being masked except the text.

[image: a]

[image]

If someone could tell me what I need to learn to solve this problem that'd be great, can this problem be solved using a shader?

Comment: Hi what do you need exactly? why do you need masking text?

Comment: I need to mask the number as I'm masking the entire card

Comment: can you make what you need in paint or photoshop and attach to your question? because I didn't understand from your attached Image.half your card rendered!

Comment: So I want everything in the red square to be masked/invisible.
https://i.imgur.com/Jg0b5RF.jpg

Comment: you should set Stencil buffer to your text to fix this issue

Answer (score 4):

If your cards are sprite you should use TextMesh because Text Component made for UI Elements.

## Sprite Solution

**Create a world space Canvas and child it to card sprite.**

[image]

**Use Sprite Mask**

[image]

**Select Visible Inside Mask**

[image]

**Change the Stencil buffer to cut the text**

[image]

**Enjoy!**

[image]

---

**UI Solution**

your game is a card game so you should use UI Elements Instead.

you can mask your Items in UI by [Mask Component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html).

**Create a canvas**

[image]

**Add Mask**

[image]

**Child them into mask**

[image]

also, you can use [SoftMaskForUGUI](https://github.com/mob-sakai/SoftMaskForUGUI) to have a better result

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I have already implemented the sprite solution.

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts you're welcome dear friend.

Comment: @CollisionOfConcepts If this solved your problem, and I see that it has, I suggest marking it as such.